# Mediatr get command name

Tags: .net-core, mediatr

At the moment we have auditting of our entities that happens in our ApplicationDbContext by checking all the entities in the changetracker.

We'd like to expand the Audit records by logging the name of the command that triggered the data manipulations.

Anyone have an example on how to get this command name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MediatR has the options to add a Pre- or Postprocessor. Read [this article](https://www.roundthecode.com/dotnet/hooking-into-mediator-pipelines)
[image: Image cited from roundthecode.com]

I.e. you could add a logger into such a processor

```cs
public class CommandPreProcessor : IRequestPreProcessor<ICommand>
{
    public CommandPreProcessor(ILogger<CommandPreProcessor> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task Process(ICommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Issued command: {commandName}", request.GetType().Name);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private readonly ILogger<CommandPreProcessor> _logger;
}
```